# how to add changeable number into header near header title

Tags: ios, uitableview, variables, swift3, header

I have a table view that has 3 sections in swift 3 - one of the header title should contain changeable number that will change many times 
here is the codes

```
import UIKit

class ProfileSettingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var cientAccount = String()



var headerList = ["اعتبار" , "یاری رسانی" , "" ]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.cientAccount.append("تومان ۱۰۰۰")

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    //////Enable Or Desable Scroll in Devices

    let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName
    if modelName == "Simulator" {

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }else if modelName == "iPhone 4s" || modelName == "iPhone 4" {

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

    }else if modelName == "iPhone SE" || modelName == "iPhone 5" || modelName == "iPhone 5c" || modelName == "iPhone 5s" || modelName == "iPod Touch 5" || modelName == "iPod Touch 6" {

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

    } else if modelName == "iPhone 6 Plus" || modelName == "iPhone 6s Plus" || modelName == "iPhone 7 Plus" {

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

    } else if modelName == "iPhone 6" || modelName == "iPhone 6s" || modelName == "iPhone 7" {

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }
    else{

        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 229/255, green: 233/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -20, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.textColor = .darkGray

    let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName
    if modelName == "iPhone 4s" || modelName == "iPhone 4" {

        label.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 15)

    }else if modelName == "iPhone SE" || modelName == "iPhone 5" || modelName == "iPhone 5c" || modelName == "iPhone 5s" || modelName == "iPod Touch 5" || modelName == "iPod Touch 6" {

        label.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 17)

    } else if modelName == "iPhone 6 Plus" || modelName == "iPhone 6s Plus" || modelName == "iPhone 7 Plus" {

        label.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 19)

    } else if modelName == "Simulator" || modelName == "iPhone 6" || modelName == "iPhone 6s" || modelName == "iPhone 7" {

        label.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 17)

    }
    else{

        label.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 15)

    }

    returnedView.addSubview(label)

    return returnedView

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow( at: indexPath , animated: true)

    if    indexPath.section == 0 {

      if  indexPath.row == 0 {

        print("افزایش اعتبار")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "oneSet", sender: self)

      } else if  indexPath.row == 1 {

        print("لیست تراکنش ها")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "twoSet", sender: self)

        }

    }
    else  if  indexPath.section == 1   {

        if indexPath.row == 0  {

            print("درباره تیپو")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "threeSet", sender: self)


        } else if indexPath.row == 1  {

            print("درباره اپلیکیشن")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "fourSet", sender: self)


        } else if  indexPath.row == 2 {

            print("تکرار معرفی")
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "introduce", sender: self)

        }

    } else if  indexPath.section == 2   {

        if indexPath.row == 0  {

        print("تنظیمات پیشرفته")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "masterSetting", sender: self)

    }

    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 37.5
}

}
```

But Xcode Doesn't allow me to use A(clientAccount)

please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
  var clientAccount = "harry"
    var headerList = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        headerList = ["A\(clientAccount)" , "B" , "C" ]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return headerList[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headerList.count
    }
```

Comment: Not Working - I have tested this many times in many different ways

Comment: what is the error i tried the above code works fine for me

Comment: I Edited the question with all of my codes please help me